# Icon and padding

Tags: html, css

`bob i {font-size: 10px}` shows a neat horizontal block, and the name titles are aligned. When I increase the `font-size` for `bob i` to `30px`, then the two `spans` are not neatly horizontally aligned anymore. The icon is not that big so why does it make the `bob span` block blow up? Is it possible to have `bob i {font-size: 40px}` and keep everything neatly horizontally aligned?

```css
.joe span
{
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}
.pete
{
 width: 30%;
 float: left;
 background-color: green;
}
.bob
{
 width: 10%;
 float: left;
 background-color: blue;
}
.bob i {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"><div class="joe"><span class="pete">Pete</span> 
<span class="bob">Bob<i class="icon">@</i></span>
</div></div>
```

Comment: try using flexbox instead of floats.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood - how that solves problem with icon padding when increasing icon size?

Comment: The answer below uses flexbox and properties to fix the column widths and center align content properly. I'd mark that correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change these class property

```
.joe span {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
}
.bob i {
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-left: 10%;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```css
.joe span {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
}
.pete
{
 width: 30%;
 float: left;
 background-color: green;
}
.bob
{
 width: 10%;
 float: left;
 background-color: blue;
}
.bob i {
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-left: 10%;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"><div class="joe"><span class="pete">Pete</span> 
<span class="bob">Bob<i class="icon">@</i></span>
</div></div>
```

Comment: floating are no more needed then, better remove them

Comment: You mean like this?